# How do I get the value of OWIN cookie right after calling IauthenticationManager.SignIn?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, cookies, asp.net-identity, owin

```
ClaimsIdentity ident = await UserManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
AuthManager.SignOut();
AuthManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties { IsPersistent = userInfo.rememberMe }, ident);
//I would like to get the value here
```

So I've tried to use `HttpContext.Request.Cookies["cookieName"].Value` but it doesn't work. In fact, when I did a `HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Count`, it returned 0.

Comment: When using AJAX authentication, we need to be sure that the sign in is completed. How to find that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Authentication manager does not set the cookie at the point. It only sets a callback with the identity object that should be written into the cookie. So `SignIn` method only stores values in the memory until the response is actually sent out. I did [write about this recently](http://tech.trailmax.info/2014/08/aspnet-identity-and-owin-who-is-who/).

Anyway, even if you get the value of a cookie, it is encrypted by OWIN and changing it's value will most likely to invalidate the cookie.

What are you trying to do with the cookie?

Comment: Useful blog post, thanks. The idea would be to store the value of the cookie when `userInfo.rememberMe` is `true` to a database table, so that I could implement something like Facebook's "Where You're Logged In" where users can see and end their "sessions". In that case, I would invalidate the cookie whenever the client with that particular cookie tries to connect.

Comment: In theory you can modify OWIN cookie to embed some sort of unique GUID which you store, but that sounds like a lot of work. Easier would be to set your own cookie with your own session identifier next to auth cookie. And if you see cookie with session that was invalidated, kill the auth cookie (not a full solution, just brainstorming)

Comment: Or a better solution would be to put a claim on identity with session ID. That claim will be part of AuthCookie and can't be messed about. And for every request put a filter to check if sessionId from claim is still valid.